# file_get_html() not working with airbnb

Tags: php, dom

I have a problem with file_get_html(), i don't understand why it doesn't work can you help me? my code

```
$html = file_get_html('https://www.airbnb.fr/');

if ($html) {
    echo "good";
}
```

Have a good day!

Comment: Can you define what you mean when you say it doesn't work?  Does it return an error message, or does it not return data?

Answer (score 0):

I think, server just blocks your request, you will not be able to fetch data from it, using simple HTTP requests.

You can try using curl, proxies, or both (there are ready to use solutions for this, like: AngryCurl, or RollingCurl)

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt work because you have to include the simple_dom_html class to make it work. You can find the code on their official page:

`http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/`

Then you can simply get the HTML and output it like this:

```
// Dump contents (without tags) from HTML
echo file_get_html('http://www.google.com/')->outertext;
```

or if you want to save the result in a variable

```
// Dump contents (without tags) from HTML
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/')->outertext;
```

More info: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/